# Surface integral over an oriented surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Given a vector field $\mathbf{F}=(A, B, C)$ in Cartesian coordinates, I understand that the line integral along an oriented curve $\mathcal{C}$ is
$$
\int_{\mathcal{C}} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{r}=\int_{\mathcal{C}} A d x+B d y+C d z
$$

But why is the surface integral over an oriented surface the following (according to my physics textbook)? I have done some multivariable calculus before but haven't seen this specific formulation being mentioned elsewhere. Some pointers would be helpful, thanks. $$ \int_{\mathcal{S}} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{d S}=\int_{\mathcal{S}} \int A d y d z+B d z d x+C d x d y $$

Comment: In general surface integrals are seen in the courses "Vectorial calculus". 
This may be helpful https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/surfaceintegrals.aspx

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari Thanks - I can solve particular problems of surface integrals (like the ones in the link) but I still don't see how the particular form of dydz / dzdx / dxdy came to be. This formula was shown while introducing differential forms and I don't understand how it's derived.

Comment: A little hint: $\mathbf{F}\cdot{\mathbf {dS}}$ involves the normal vector to the surface and that has a lot to do with a cross product of tangent vectors to the surface which in turn has a lot to do with the wedge products $dy\wedge dz,dz\wedge dx,dx\wedge dy\,.$

Comment: [If you're willing to look at things more generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4302863/568204).

Comment: If at some point you decide to learn a bit about differential forms and see this in a coherent manner, some of [my YouTube lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) may be helpful. You can get the gist of the computations in lectures 34-35 (MATH 3510) and the discussion of flux (which is what your integral above is calculating). Starting at minute 20 of lecture 41 is a dictionary between the differential form approach and the standard "physics" approach in $\Bbb R^3$.